# Generate mutiple physical table from single class Map in Nhibernate mapping by code

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have a single ClassMapping and I want to generate multiple physical tables which are not known during compile time. For example, I want to use Table1, Table2, Table3, etc from the single class Map.

I tried the following code, But the model mapper add only one class Map and it updates the previous class map again. Not adding another class map.

```
private static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
    {
        var cfg = new Configuration();
        cfg.CurrentSessionContext<ThreadStaticSessionContext>();
        cfg.Configure();
        var mapper = new ModelMapper();
        mapper.AddMappings(typeof(ClientMap).Assembly.GetTypes());
        AddDynamicTables(mapper);
        cfg.AddMapping(mapper.CompileMappingForAllExplicitlyAddedEntities());
        BuildSchema(cfg);
        return cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
    }

private static void AddDynamicTables(ModelMapper mapper)
    {
        var clients = new List<string>() { "First", "Second" };
        foreach (var client in clients)
        {
            var map = new ClassMapping<Rule>();
            map.EntityName("tbl_" + client + "_rules");
            map.Id(x => x.Id);
            map.Property(x => x.RuleId);
            map.Property(x => x.ShortName);
            map.Property(x => x.IsActive);
            map.Property(x => x.Description);
            map.Property(x => x.Type);
            map.Property(x => x.RuleGroup);
            map.Table("tbl_" + client + "_rules");
            mapper.AddMapping(map);
        }
    }
```

I think this is because of the Merge in customizerHolder. How do I create a variable number of tables from a single class Map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to create multiple tables from the same map by creating different new model mapper in the foreach, use compile mapping on for each and add to the configuration.

```
private static void AddDynamicTables(Configuration cfg)
    {
        var clients = new List<string>() { "First", "Second" };
        foreach (var client in clients)
        {
            var mapper = new ModelMapper();
            var map = new ClassMapping<Rule>();
            map.EntityName("tbl_" + client + "_rules");
            map.Property(x=>x.RuleId);
            map.Table("tbl_" + client + "_rules");
            mapper.AddMapping(map);
            var mappings = mapper.CompileMappingForAllExplicitlyAddedEntities();
            cfg.AddMapping(mappings);
        }
    }
```